# Youtube on JWPlayer on iOS

Tags: javascript, youtube, jwplayer, jwplayer6

I am using JWPlayer to embed YouTube videos. I chose it because it supports SRT subs, and I can add subtitles to YouTube videos that I don't own. Which is absolutely great.

The issue is, when I play the video on iOS, it automatically switches to YouTube player which lacks the SRT feature.

Can I force JWPlayer not to failover to YouTube player and only stick to HTML5 to avoid losing the SRT feature?

Comment: The short answer is that no, you can't, at least not in the current version. JW Player uses the YouTube player when on iOS. There's no known way to prevent that.

Comment: @MisterNeutron it possible, jwplayer doesn't fallback to YouTube player on iOS or android.

Comment: Yes, I believe that's true in 6.9. But 6.9 has been released only to those using the cloud-hosted version of the player. It hasn't been pumped out to the self-hosters or WP plugin users yet. Soon, I'm sure.

Comment: We are planning on updating the self hosted copy of JW6 to 6.8 either today or tomorrow (early this week), I believe.

Answer (score 1):

JWPlayer version 6.9 support YouTube embed via jwplayer instead regular YouTube player.

See this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/UAR3U/19/
It works on browser, desktop or mobile.

```
 jwplayer("container").setup({
  file:'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tRm04aUyOrM',
      width: "80%",
     aspectratio: "16:9",
   stretching: 'exactfit',
tracks: [{ 
    file: 'http://content.jwplatform.com/tracks/2UEDrDhv.txt', 
    label: 'English', 
    kind: 'captions', default:true
  }]
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing, it automatically switches to YouTube player on iOS.

Comment: You must be using 6.8 then. If you use 6.9, it will be a different embed method (YouTube Via JWP).

Answer (score 0):

I have made the dirty hack, but it works - http://jsfiddle.net/2o0mnpfp/4/

HTML:

```
<div id="container-holder" class="inactive">
    <div id="container"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
jwplayer("container").setup({
    file:'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tRm04aUyOrM'
});
jwplayer("container").onPlay(function () {
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('container-holder').className = '';
    }, 1000);
});
```

CSS:

```
.inactive .jwvideo {
    z-index: 1!important;
    opacity: 0!important;
}
.inactive .jwcontrols {
    display: block!important;
}
.inactive .jwdisplayIcon {
    opacity: 1!important;
    visibility: visible!important;
    display: table!important;
}
```